# Can't open database on 2nd user account, error EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, database, multi-user

I have some problems with an app of mine and a Galaxy Nexus 10 with multi user support. My app has to copy a database, this works fine when I am logged in as the first user of the tablet, but it fails with

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/packagename/dbname.db: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

when I am logged in with the second account.
The second account seems to have no rights to write to /data/data...

So, what can be done about it? I already read some of the topics concerning this problem, still no answer which satisfies me. Is there a folder which can be used to share data between users?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The second account seems to have no rights to write to /data/data...

Correct.

> So, what can be done about it?

I am guessing that you hard-coded a path. If so, do not do this. Use `getDatabasePath()` to find the proper path to the database *for the current user*.

> Is there a folder which can be used to share data between users?!

Not that I am aware of. Even external storage is separate between users. In effect, separate user accounts on a device are as if those users are on completely separate devices.

Comment: wrt folder shared between users: the following folder is visible for all users: "/sdcard/Android/obb", at least on my nexus7-gen1, running android 4.4.2

Comment: .... yet, I'm not sure if that is intentional / guaranteed; that folder has a specific use it seems: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#StorageLocation

Comment: So what the hell do we do when it's an app we've installed from the Play store!?